# Does a transaction end after the program got closed?

Tags: java, database, postgresql, hibernate, tomcat

I am trying to run a web application with the result that it's not able to process further. So it seems it is "locked" somehow (It stayes at the "Start in progress..."-process until it crashes).

After thinking about what could be the cause, I remembered that I didn't stop a transaction.

I just entered the command

```
entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
```

but haven't stopped or closed the transaction.

**So my question is:**

Do transactions stop after the program got closed? 
And if not, do you know how I can stop the transaction the easiest way?

PS: Please correct every grammar-mistake I've made - I just like questions which are beautifully formulated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database is going to see a connection being closed, so the transaction is definitely going to end. What's not defined is whether the transaction is committed or rolled back.

If I'm not mistaken the more popular option is to rollback any uncommitted transactions (after all it indicates that something's gone wrong and you'd prefer a rollback), but this can depend on the database being used.

Comment: But I wonder why the program (or hibernate) cannot process further. Hibernate seems to hang somewhere

Comment: Most likely a deadlock. You'll need to inspect your database to see what's going on there.

Comment: It went to PgAdmin and closed all current open sessions. Then I closed all transaction when I opened them. And its working now!
The transaction (or the session) has really been open although the program got closed.

Comment: That means you've leaked a connection. Although are you saying that the connection remained open even though the JVM exited?

Comment: It remained open when I didn't close the "EntityManager", yes. When I close the EntityManager, the session closes with the program.

Comment: Well that's normal. You were talking about "closing the program", which is not at all the same thing as "I'm leaving my transaction and entitymanager open".

Comment: So when I close my program, the transaction gets closed too, but the session with the database (created with my "EntityManager") remains?

And therefore I can't access the tables in the db anymore because it is locked!